# Spring service going down after DB connection down

Tags: spring, cxf, jdbctemplate

I have a spring cxf web service application deployed into a JBOSS server. The service is working fine and once in a while(within 5-6 days after the server start) , I get and error"Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object" and that particular service goes down

I have around 17 services inside this application and only the service which had this DB connection issue goes down till I restart the server.

Other services are up.

Below is my JDBC template configuration.

```
<bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="10" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="10" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="100" />
        <property name="maxWait" value="1000" />
        <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1" />
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1200000" />
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000" />
        <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="5" />
        <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" />
    </bean>
```

Your help is greately appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you switch to a JNDI data source managed by JBOSS.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like either a connection leak or that you have some really long-running processes that hold a database connection long-term, eventually exhausting your connection pool. It's also possible, though unlikely, that you have very high database latency, that a dead connection shows up in the pool, and that recognizing the dead connection, establishing a new one, and validating it takes longer than the 1 second you've given the pool.

Comment: yes that is correct. I am using a database which is consumed by a number of applications.I am working on the connection leak issues. But my real problem is how can I prevent the service going down issue. Is there any way to keep the service alive even if it has connectivity issues.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "going down". Just being unable to get a connection should only cause problems with the request where that problem occurs. Subsequent requests can still be serviced; however, if the pool is still exhausted, they'll obviously fail also. If that's the case, then fixing the connection leaks is the *only* right answer.

Comment: Going down means the particular services for which the connection leak happened, never come back till we restart the server.All other services will work fine.it looks like some configuration in spring shuts down server ( don't know is it because of the singleton implementation of service)

Comment: That still doesn't quite describe it. When the service "goes down" and you make more requests to it, what response do you get? Is it a 503? 500? 404? Or does the request just hang forever?

Comment: When the service goes down, I get the same response "Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object" eventhough the DB is up. Also all other services which is within the war and has the DB activities works fine.

Comment: Exactly, so the service isn't down. Its connection pool is exhausted. Just fix the connection leak.

Comment: What did you do to fix your connection leak? We have exactly the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

You can try and change the datasource to the : 
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource

It's better to configure a data source with JBoss and do a Java EE-jndi lookup.
http://techdive.in/spring/spring-jndi-datasource-configuration-jboss

Comment: Absolutely [*do not* use a DriverManagerDataSource for production](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DriverManagerDataSource.html) unless you fully understand the implications.